# Java: Calculate number of do/while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

So I've made this guessing game where you the computer randomly picks a number between 1-100 and the user have to guess the correct number. I've made that working, now I want to calculate how many times the loop has repeated itself if you may say, or well how many times the user has "guessed".

This is the current code:

```
int random = 0;
int a;
random = ((int)(Math.random()*100+1));
System.out.println("Guess the number");     
do          
{       
    a = Keyboard.readInt();     
    if (a > random) 
    {
        System.out.println("Less");
    }
    if (a == random)
    {
        System.out.println("Correct");
    }
    if (a < random)
    {
        System.out.println("More");
    }
}
while (a != random);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int random = 0,guessed=0;
int a;
random = ((int)(Math.random()*100+1));
System.out.println("Guess the number");     
do          
{    
   guessed++;
a = Keyboard.readInt();     
if (a > random) 
{
    System.out.println("Less");
}
if (a == random)
{
    System.out.println("Correct");
    System.out.println("Guessed" +guessed +"times ";
}
if (a < random)
{
    System.out.println("More");
}
}

while (a != random);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a counter variable:

```
int guessCount = 0;

do {
guessCount++;
...
} while (...)
```

At the end of the loop, you can print the guess count.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add an `int guesses = 0;` variable, and increment it at the top of the `do` block.